# Looping 1-10 PRINT either only EVEN, only ODDS, or ALL

Tags: python, loops, python-2.7, while-loop

The program loops 1-10 but the user can choose whether they want
to print only the even numbers, only the odd numbers, or all the numbers.

So, if the user choose to print only evens then the output should be:
  2 4 6 8 10

If only odd: 1 3 5 7 9

All: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

But when I run my code below, it works normally for print all but for print only
even or print only odd then it won't run the program at all. So I was wondering
what may be the mistakes here.

```
MODE = ["Only Even", "Only Odds", "All Numbers"]
for i,v in enumerate(MODE):
    print i+1, v
count = 0
s = int(input("Enter Mode Wanted: "))
if s == 3:
    while count < 10:
        print count+1
    count += 1
elif s == 2:
    while count <=10:
        if count%2 != 0:
            print count
    count += 1
elif s == 1:
    while count <= 10:
        if count%2 == 0:
            print count
    count += 1
```

Comment: I've made some more changes to my code. Be sure to check them out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `count += 1` indentation is wrong.

CORRECTED:

```
MODE = ["Only Even", "Only Odds", "All Numbers"]
for i,v in enumerate(MODE):
    print i+1, v
count = 1                 #changed 0 to 1
s = int(raw_input("Enter Mode Wanted: "))
if s == 3:
    while count <= 10:    #changed < to <=
        print count       #changed count+1 to count
        count += 1
elif s == 2:
    while count <=10:
        if count%2 != 0:
            print count
        count += 1
elif s == 1:
    while count <= 10:
        if count%2 == 0:
            print count
        count += 1
```

Comment: So my biggest mistake was the indentation of  count += 1 ryt? But why didn't the program run when I enter s = 1 or 2 in my code, does it have to do with the indentation? or is there other reason?

Comment: @avoid_frustration, Please try my code as is. I made very few adjustments to it. It works. I tested it

Comment: Yea, I've tried and it works! I was just wondering what were my mistakes.

Comment: @avoid_frustration, I'm not sure. I just copied your code and edited some of it. You can see where I put the comments.

Comment: Yea, the comments helps! Thanks for the answer, did help a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

First, rather than use a `while` loop, you should use a `for` loop in cases like this, where you know what you are iterating over:

```
for count in range(1, 11):
```

thus saving you from the error of forgetting to manually increment `count` (or incrementing it in the wrong place, in this case).

Second, you should run this loop only once, and move your rules inside it:

```
for count in range(1, 11):    
    if (s == 3 or 
        (s == 2 and count % 2 != 0) or 
        (s == 1 and count % s == 0)):
        print count
```

Note how this significantly reduces duplication and, thus, potential for error.

Finally, you can use [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response), `str.format` and the optional second argument to `enumerate` to improve your user input:

```
MODE = ["Only Even", "Only Odds", "All Numbers"]
for i, v in enumerate(MODE, 1):
    print "{0}: {1}".format(i, v)
while True:
    try:
        s = int(input("Enter mode wanted: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Not an integer.")
    else:
        if s in range(1, len(MODE) + 1):
            break
        print("Not a valid mode.") 
for count in range(1, 11):
    ...
```